# Will an answerer get score for a new tag if it is added into a question?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

If we consider, Person A answers Question Q1, where the question initially has only two tags, Java and PHP, added by the asker.

Now some person comes and adds another tag, say, MySQL.

If 10 people upvoted my answer, will my tag score for the Java, PHP, *and* MySQL tags increase by 10 points? Or will my tag score increase for only the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tags, as those were tags added at first place?

To clarify, have a look:
[image]

Comment: You mean score, not reputation.  Reputation isn't measured per tag.

Comment: @Servy , hi I updated question

Comment: Yes, and that's measuring score (sum of upvotes minus downvotes), not reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tag scores are recalculated once per day, based on all your currently visible posts.

It doesn't matter whether you have any deleted posts, nor whether they ever had other tags.

(As an aside, the tag-score-update has a history of failing on SO: [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226681))

Comment: You mean `All` scores on `All` tags I earned till now will be calculated?

Comment: Yes. Also, your tag-badges will be recalculated. (Tag-badges are the only badges one can ever loose, unless there was blatant fraud and the community managers (not just mods) step in.)